# Identify count of datatypes in a column which has multiple datatypes

Tags: pyspark

When I read an excel file, it has a column like this,

```
Col1
----
aaa
123
true
235
321
23.23
xxx
```

I need to identify how many datatypes we have in this column. When the data is big the processing time is also big. Any options in pyspark?

Regards,
Ash

Answer (score 1):

`spark` doesn't have built in udfs to return the value data type, so implement `udf` to return data type, you can extend the function defined here for other data types long, using `regexp` also an option

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def get_data_type(val):
    data_type = None
    try:
        float(val)
        data_type = "float"
    except ValueError:
        if (data_type != None and val.isnumeric()):
            data_type = 'int'
        else:
            if (val.lower() in ("yes", "no", "true", "false")):
                data_type = 'boolean'
            else:
                data_type = "string"
    else:
        if float(val).is_integer():
            data_type = "int"
    return data_type

get_data_type_udf = F.udf(get_data_type, T.StringType())

df = spark.createDataFrame(['aaa','123','true','235','321','23.23'], T.StringType()).toDF("col1")
df = df.select(get_data_type_udf(F.col("col1")).alias("data_type")).groupBy("data_type").count()
df.show()
```

which results

```
+---------+-----+
|data_type|count|
+---------+-----+
|      int|    3|
|  boolean|    1|
|   string|    1|
|    float|    1|
+---------+-----+
```

Comment: I'm doing this but with a slight change, but when the dataset is huge, it is becoming difficult. Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to load the data first to a `string` column and then you could play a bit by applying some logic to identify the types. Here's an example how you could start by differentiating text from numeric columns. I guess it should be easy to tell whether a number is float or int, etc.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"), 
    (2, "123"),
    (3, "22.12"),
    (4, "c"),
    (5, "True")
], ("ID","mixed_data"))

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

casted = df.select("ID", "mixed_data",F.when(F.col("mixed_data").cast('float').isNull(), "text").otherwise("some kind of number").alias("guessed_type"))

+---+----------+-------------------+
| ID|mixed_data|       guessed_type|
+---+----------+-------------------+
|  1|         a|               text|
|  2|       123|some kind of number|
|  3|     22.12|some kind of number|
|  4|         c|               text|
|  5|      True|               text|
+---+----------+-------------------+
```