# How to infer datatypes of an existing Spark Dataframe?

Tags: schema, etl, aws-glue, pyspark

I have pivoted a long dataframe to wide. This new dataframe has many more new variables coming out of the pivot. These are all stringType in the Spark Dataframe. How could I get pyspark to re-infer the datatypes of those new columns so that decimals will be recognised as float/double instead of strings?

Background: The number of these new columns per table and the number of pivoted tables are too large to hand-build the schemas.

It would be nice if there is something similar to `infer_objects()` from Pandas, but within PySpark. I cannot use Pandas because the job lives in AWS Glue Spark, which offers no Pandas library.

Comment: maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860160/identify-count-of-datatypes-in-a-column-which-has-multiple-datatypes/59862357#59862357

Comment: Thx mrjoseph, this approach is worth considering if there is no better solution. Only that running it over many tables, each with many columns may be cumbersome. Oh! and it wouldn't work if there is a missing value in a float column.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ResolveChoice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html) Class to handle your problem. You can choose one of the action type that are listed in documentation.

> cast:  Allows you to specify a type to cast to (for example, cast:int).
>
> make_cols:  Resolves a potential ambiguity by flattening the data. For example, if columnA could be an int or a string, the resolution is to produce two columns named columnA_int and columnA_string in the resulting DynamicFrame.
>
> make_struct:  Resolves a potential ambiguity by using a struct to represent the data. For example, if data in a column could be an int or a string, using the make_struct action produces a column of structures in the resulting DynamicFrame with each containing both an int and a string.
>
> project:  Resolves a potential ambiguity by retaining only values of a specified type in the resulting DynamicFrame. For example, if data in a ChoiceType column could be an int or a string, specifying a project:string action drops columns from the resulting DynamicFrame which are not type string.

To check all possible type firstly, you can use *make_struct* action type then you can use *cast* action or you can use *make_cols* action type and glue generate all possible type as new columns.

I'm going to share sample code block below.

```
resolvechoiceA = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = datasourceA, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoiceA")
```

I hope this answer can solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, serkan I think you misunderstood the problem. The Dataframe is already there, and there are no choices to be resolved! All the new columns are stringType. I need to run recomputeSchema (Scala method) from PySpark. If you know how to do that via sc._jvm, that would be appreciated

Comment: @axiom From your question my understanding is you just want to change the type in your dataframe. So ResolveChoice makes it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, here it is.
As of Feb. 2020, there is no solution to this problem within PySpark, other than using `infer_objects()` form Pandas. If you cannot use Pandas because you are in AWS Glue, then you are lucky and unlucky. Unlucky - because Pandas isn't available; lucky - because there is something even better, which is `recomputeSchema()` in Scala.

All you have to do is

1. Start with DynamicFrame `dyf`
2. Move the `dyf` to Java with `dyf._jdf`
3. Use the `recomputeSchema()` method in Scala `dyf._jdf.recomputeSchema()`, which returns a schema.
4. Catch the schema with `toString()` method and `_deserialize_json_string( )` function

The code would be

```
    from awsglue.gluetypes import _deserialize_json_string
    newSchema=_deserialize_json_string( dyf._jdf.recomputeSchema().toString() ) )
```

Then you can get to resolving choices as serkan mentioned.